# Python Regular Expressions: Capture lookahead value (capturing text without consuming it)

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-lookarounds

I wish to use regular expressions to split words into groups of `(vowels, not_vowels, more_vowels)`, using a marker to ensure every word begins and ends with a vowel.

```
import re

MARKER = "~"
VOWELS = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u", MARKER}

word = "dog"

if word[0] not in VOWELS:
    word = MARKER+word

if word[-1] not in VOWELS:
    word += MARKER

re.findall("([%]+)([^%]+)([%]+)".replace("%", "".join(VOWELS)), word)
```

In this example we get:

```
[('~', 'd', 'o')]
```

The issue is that I wish the matches to overlap - the last set of vowels should become the first set of the next match. This appears possible with lookaheads, if we replace the regex as follows:

```
re.findall("([%]+)([^%]+)(?=[%]+)".replace("%", "".join(VOWELS)), word)
```

We get:

```
[('~', 'd'), ('o', 'g')]
```

Which means we are matching what I want. However, it now doesn't return the last set of vowels. The output I want is:

```
[('~', 'd', 'o'), ('o', 'g', '~')]
```

I feel this should be possible (if the regex can check for the second set of vowels, I see no reason it can't return them), but I can't find any way of doing it beyond the brute force method, looping through the results after I have them and appending the first character of the next match to the last match, and the last character of the string to the last match. Is there a better way in which I can do this?

The two things that would work would be capturing the lookahead value, or not consuming the text on a match, while capturing the value - I can't find any way of doing either.

Comment: Any particular reason why I got a downvote on this one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found it just after posting:

```
re.findall("([%]+)([^%]+)(?=([%]+))".replace("%", "".join(VOWELS)), word)
```

Adding an extra pair of brackets inside the lookahead means that it becomes a capture itself.

I found this pretty obscure and hard to find - I'm not sure if it's just everyone else found this obvious, but hopefully anyone else in my position will find this more easily in future.

Comment: This is the standard way to find overlapping matches, BTW.

Comment: Yeah, `(?...)` brackets no longer capture. This is why `(?:)` exists: so that you can explicitly avoid capturing something that still needs to be grouped. In your case you need to capture it anyway, so you just explicitly add capturing brackets.

Comment: This just shows my lack of regex knowledge I guess. Good to learn something new.

Comment: @Lattyware: +1 Thanks, it helped me. I was not aware that one can use `()` inside look-ahead and make it capture.

Answer (score 3):

I would not try to make the regex engine do this; I would split the string into consonant and vowel chunks, and then generate the overlapping results. This way, you also don't actually need to hack in markers, assuming you're okay with `''` as the "vowel" part when the word doesn't actually being or end with a vowel.

```
def overlapping_matches(word):
    pieces = re.split('([^aeiou]+)', word)
    # There are other ways to do this; I'm kinda showing off
    return zip(pieces[:-2], pieces[1:-1], pieces[2:])[::2]

overlapping_matches('dog') # [('', 'd', 'o'), ('o', 'g', '')]
```

(This still fails if `word` contains only vowels, but that is trivially corrected if necessary.)

Comment: +1. It's a nice solution, but I don't feel it's as readable as the solution I found.